# How to close Android recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, cache, delete

I want to wipe cache partition on android recovery mode. But I dont know how to close it. In my phone the screen is seems like this photo

[image]

After eipe cache partition what should I type to turn it off and go to my home screen

Comment: please note the cache partition is not used for apps cache. reason why one will wipe cache partition is to cancel already scheduled OTA installation or delete recovery logs

Answer (score 1):

Simply click on "Reboot system now".